# Copy all subdirectory names and files with a particular extension to a new directory

Tags: command-line

I have the following directory structure:

```
dir1
    py1.py
    py2.py
    subdir1
        file1.py
        anotherfile.txt
    subdir2
        file2.py
        animage.png
```

I would like to copy the folder structure and the *.py files (except those belonging directly to dir1) to a new directory at the same level as dir1. That is, I'm looking for this:

```
dir2
    subdir1
        file1.py
    subdir2
        file2.py
```

I tried (from the layer above dir1):

```
mkdir dir2
cp -r *.py ../dir2
```

But this only copied the *.py files from dir 1 into dir2, and ignored the subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `find` and `cpio`, just `cd` into `dir1` and run this:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*.py" -print | cpio -pdm ../dir2
```

- `find .` will start in the current directory ie. `dir1`
- `-mindepth 2` will ignore the contents of the current directory ie. `dir1` and include the contents of its sub-directories.
- `-type f -name "*.py" -print` will include only files with `.py` extension.
- `cpio -pdm` will copy. `-p` creates a list of files, `-d` creates directories as needed and `-m` sets the correct modification times on directories.
- `../dir2` will create a directory ( if it does not exist ) named `dir2` one level up next to `dir1` and copy everything to it.

For reference [man find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html) and [man cpio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bsdcpio.1.html).

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

You could use a shell glob, with the `--parents` option of `cp`

Ex. given

```
$ tree dir1 dir2
dir1
├── py1.py
├── py2.py
├── subdir1
│   ├── anotherfile.txt
│   └── file1.py
└── subdir2
    ├── animage.png
    └── file2.py
dir2

2 directories, 6 files
```

(note that `dir2` already exists) then

```
$ cd dir1
$ cp --parents -t ../dir2 **/*.py
$ cd ..
```

gives

```
$ tree dir1 dir2
dir1
├── py1.py
├── py2.py
├── subdir1
│   ├── anotherfile.txt
│   └── file1.py
└── subdir2
    ├── animage.png
    └── file2.py
dir2
├── subdir1
│   └── file1.py
└── subdir2
    └── file2.py

4 directories, 8 files
```

I used the `globstar` pattern `**` but if you only need to descend one level you could use a basic `*` wildcard for the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsync`:

```
mkdir dir2
rsync -amv --include '*/' --include '*/*.py' --exclude '*' dir1/ dir2
```

This will copy all `.py` files starting from the second level.

- `-m` avoid creating empty directories.
- `--include '*/'` Include all directories
- `--include '*/*.py'` Include all `.py` files starting at second level

  - Change to `'/*/*.py'` if you want to include *only* second level `.py` files
- `--exclude '*'` Exclude everything that is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I couldn't find a way to make cp or rsync by themselves do what you want, so I've come up with:

```
for n in dir1/* ; do ls ${n}/*.py >/dev/null 2>&1 ; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then mkdir dir2/${n/dir1\//} ; cp ${n}/*.py dir2/${n/dir1\//} ; fi ; done
```

Indenting it properly makes it more readable:

```
for n in dir1/* 
do
  ls ${n}/*.py >/dev/null 2>&1 
  if [[ $? == 0 ]]
  then
    mkdir dir2/${n/dir1\//} 
    cp ${n}/*.py dir2/${n/dir1\//} 
  fi
done
```

So, what I'm doing is looking through dir1, assuming each file is a directory and trying to list any *.py files (with output and error disappearing into /dev/null). Obviously, trying this for py1.py and py2.py will fail because they are not directories. It should also fail for any directories that do not have any *.py files in them.

That means that when we are in the if, the result of the previous command ($?) should be something other than 0 and we do nothing. For the subdirs in dir1, the listing should succeed, and so $? will be 0, so we perform the bit inside the loop. That merely creates the subdir in dir2 (remembering to replace "dir1/" with nothing), and copies any *.py files across.

It's certainly not the only way to do this, and while it works for the example you gave, it doesn't work if you have extra levels of subdirs inside subdirs. (e.g. `dir1/subdir1/subsubdir1/*.py` will *not* be copied across)